# How should I use Site.createPersonAccountPortalUser to create a Person Account and activate them on the portal in one step?

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, customer-portal, person-accounts, portal

I have a method below which is supposed to be called from an unauthenticated Sites page (via https). It is intended to take some personal details and create a Person Account with them and then activate that record for use on the customer portal.

However when I run this method I find that the return value of the Site.createPersonAccountPortalUser method is null and the person account is not created.

I have been trying to follow the instructions from the [Site Class documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_sites.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_classes_sites.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) without success.

I have set up a force.com site, associated it to a customer portal, enabled the profile and defined a default user profile and licence to be high-volume portal user.

```
public static String createPersonAccountPortalUser(String FirstName, String LastName, String Email, String Phone, Map<String, String> mResponseMap){
    ID userId;
    User u = new User();

    //Name and email are required.
    if(FirstName != null && FirstName != '' && LastName != null && LastName != ''){
        if(Email != null && Email != ''){
            u.FirstName =FirstName;
            u.LastName =LastName;
            u.Username = Email;
            u.Email = Email;
            u.Phone = Phone;
            u.CommunityNickname = LastName;             
            system.debug('## createPersonAccountPortalUser: user =' + u);
            system.debug('## createPersonAccountPortalUser: PortalOwnerId = ' + PortalOwnerId);
            String strRecTypeId = queryForPersonRecType();
            try{
                userId = Site.createPersonAccountPortalUser(u, PortalOwnerId, 'testpassword');
                system.debug('## createPersonAccountPortalUser: userId = ' + userId);
                mResponseMap.put(KeyId, userId);
                UtilityMap.appendValue(KeyStatus, SuccessNewPersonAccount, mResponseMap);
                return userId;                                      
            }catch(Exception e){
                UtilityMap.appendValue(KeyError, FailureNewPersonAccount, mResponseMap);
                mResponseMap.put(KeyErrorMessage, EncodingUtil.urlEncode(e.getMessage(), 'UTF-8'));
                return null;
            }                               
        }else{UtilityMap.appendValue(KeyError, EmailErr, mResponseMap);}            
    }else{UtilityMap.appendValue(KeyError, NamesRequired, mResponseMap);}
    return userId;      
}
```

I have also tried running the following code as anonymous apex in the developer console and I still get a null returned.

```
User u = new User();
u.FirstName ='FirstName';
u.LastName ='LastName';
u.Username = 'testuser';
u.Email = 'testuser@magardner.co.uk';
u.Phone = 'Phone';
u.CommunityNickname = 'LastName';
String userId = Site.createPersonAccountPortalUser(u, Label.B2C_Portal_Person_Account_Owner_Id, 'testpass');
system.debug('user Id = ' + userId);
```

What am I doing wrong?

For reference here is my visualforce page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="ServiceRegistrationController" action="{!createRegistration}" contentType="application/json">
<apex:outputText value="{!response}" escape="false"/>
```

Comment: How are you getting `PortalOwnerId`? Are you able to manually create a portal user with that owner?

Comment: I'm defining that as a hard coded value from a custom label so it can be changed in-life.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are able to manually create a portal user with that owner?

Comment: Yes I have just tested that and it works OK through the salesforce UI.

Comment: I'm stumped - I'll ask the gurus in the Portal team...

Comment: Can you check once more please that you have assigned a valid Default recordtype to the Guest User Profile ?

Comment: Good suggestion @MohithKumar I hadn't set the default record type on the Portal guest user profile. However once I set it to person account I still get null returned from the create portal method. I have also tried running the method from the developer console and I get the same result.

Comment: Can you check same for the portal profile you have associated for site may be we have missed there?

Comment: Yes @MohithKumar the person account record type is the default for the account object.

Comment: Just looking at this page http://blogs.developerforce.com/isv/2009/04/provisioning-customer-portal-users-with-apex.html it has some more detail about creating portal users via apex that I've not tried yet.

Comment: Hmm perhaps this is relevant... I am doing mixed Setup and Non Setup DML. Apex does not allow DML operations of a non-setup sObject and a setup sObject in a single Apex transaction. In this example, the rule prevents us from creating the Contact record in the same transaction as the User record. The Contact is the non-setup sObject type, but the User is a setup type sObject, and therefore Apex won't allow us to have such mixed DML operations in a single transaction. To solve this, the Apex code creates the Contact record synchronously, but it uses the @future annotation to create the User.

Comment: We use that successfully.  There should not be a mixed dml issue.  Can you post the page itself?  Is your form force-ssl = true ?  Does it work from a page in the site?  I don't know that it will work as a static method.  We've discovered that other site methods, like login, don't work from static or remote, only from an apex form on a vf page

Comment: Hi @ShaneMcLaughlin no the form is not force-ssl=true. The vf page is provided as an unauthenticated page in order to mimic the behaviour of the Web2Lead service. Interesting to hear about it perhaps being down to being called from a static method. I've added the vf page to the question however it just returns a json string when called so not too interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some further information here: [Provisioning Customer Portal Users with Apex](http://blogs.developerforce.com/isv/2009/04/provisioning-customer-portal-users-with-apex.html)

This post suggests that the problem is that you cannot create a contact and a user record in the same APEX transaction. Doing so is called mixed DML and is not allowed. Therefore if you must create a contact and user at the same time the only way to do so is for one of them to be created asynchronously via a method marked with the @future annotation.

This is the method I have used.

```
    //Async method, using @future, to create the User record and associate it to the previously created Contact
    //This uses @future because you can not have mixed DML operations for standard objects (Account, Contact) and Setup objects(User)
    @future public static void createUser(String contactId, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String profileId) {
        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
        //take the first few characters of the username for the alias
        String alias = userName.substring(0, 7);
        User u = new User(alias = alias, email=email, 
            emailencodingkey=EmailEncoding, lastname=lastname, languagelocalekey=LanguageLocaleKey, 
            localesidkey=LocaleSidKey, profileid = profileId, contactId=contactId,
            timezonesidkey=TimeZoneSidKey, username=username);

        u.setOptions(dmo);
        insert u;
    }
```

This appears to be working better than my previous attempt. The error messages now show up in the Apex Jobs page (Administration Setup > Monitoring > Apex Jobs) which makes it easier to debug than the silence that the first attempt gave.

Comment: So are you not using the createPersonAccountPortalUser method at all now?

Comment: No I gave up on that method.